# drag and drop sortable list in rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, html, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I want the drag and drop functionality in my rails apps.I was trying to do this by watching

```
http://railscasts.com/episodes/147-sortable-lists
```

In my case i have two model one is project and another is task model.
project model :

```
 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :user_id
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks
 end
```

task model:

```
 class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :project_id, :project
  belongs_to :project
 end
```

Now i want the drag and drop sortable list at the project show page.In project show page :

```
           <p>
      <b>Title:</b>
      <%= @project.title %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <b>User:</b>
      <%= @project.user_id %>
    </p>

        <ul id="tasks">
          <% for task in @project.tasks %>
              <span4>
                <% content_tag_for :li, task do %>
                  <%= task.title %>

                <hr />
                <% end %>
              </span4>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
        <%= sortable_element("tasks", :url => sort_project_path ) %>

    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(@project) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', projects_path %>
```

In projects conteoller i have sort method:

```
  def sort
   params[:taks].each_with_index do |id, index|
    Task.update_all(['position=?', index+1], ['id=?', id])
   end
   render :nothing => true
  end
```

In my routes file i have:

```
 resources :projects do
  member do
   post :sort
  end
 end
```

I followed every instruction rain bates says in the video but no luck.I got this error.

```
  undefined method `sortable_element' for #<#<Class:0x007f4c6c193a60>:0x007f4c6c199780>
```

I searched for it then i found this method is deprecated .Now i have no idea how to do drag and drop functionality as i am a new bee.

Please help me . 
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`sortable_element` was taken out in Rails 3.1 onwards I'm afraid. That is why you're getting a method not found error!

We have just upgraded a Rails app to 3.2 and are having similar problems. I have no solution yet I'm afraid.